# Can Live Mail be set to perform operations asynchronously

Tags: imap, windows-live-mail, gmail-imap

I have Microsoft Live Mail attached to two different IMAP mail accounts. When I delete a message, the UI sometimes freezes.  Is there a way to set Live Mail so such operations do not block the UI?

Answer (score 1):

If you are a developer at Microsoft Live, yes; if not, no.

Comment: I understand this answer to mean that mere mortals must twiddle our barely opposable thumbs.